# need help determining why ios Subliminal tests will randomly hang at different tests and and at different points during a test suite run

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, automation, subliminal

When running my test suite through Xcode or through the command-line, I have noticed that the tests will sit and hang for no apparent reason. I have no clue why the test will suddenly hang. The test will essentially hang forever or until I stop it. I have about 19 lengthy tests that are supposed to run but it gets to the 3rd or 4th or 5th test and then it just randomly stops.

By the way, when I run each test individually, they all will completely run when executing the solo test.

I wish the test would just error or the entire suite would bomb out but that just doesnt happen and instead I get a test run that last forever. Please help! I would be more than willing to give you logs but unfortunately all I have are the instruments logs which are not useful for debugging.

**EDIT****
Here is the sample requested from the comments:

```
Analysis of sampling instruments (pid 49112) every 1 millisecond
Process:         instruments [49112]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
Load Address:    0x10ab3c000
Identifier:      instruments
Version:         $[MARKETING_VERSION] (51168)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  sh [47591]

Date/Time:       2013-12-03 15:24:05.120 -0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
Report Version:  7

Call graph:
    9132 Thread_10178874   DispatchQueue_1: com.apple.main-thread  (serial)
    + 9132 start  (in libdyld.dylib) + 1  [0x7fff870e87e1]
    +   9132 ???  (in instruments)  load address 0x10ab3c000 + 0x4736  [0x10ab40736]
    +     9132 ???  (in instruments)  load address 0x10ab3c000 + 0x41a8  [0x10ab401a8]
    +       9132 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:]  (in Foundation) + 78  [0x7fff8209a69b]
    +         9132 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:]  (in Foundation) + 268  [0x7fff8209a7ee]
    +           9132 CFRunLoopRunSpecific  (in CoreFoundation) + 290  [0x7fff83a670e2]
    +             9125 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1078  [0x7fff83a67916]
    +             ! 9125 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort  (in CoreFoundation) + 195  [0x7fff83a62233]
    +             !   9125 mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 70  [0x7fff8a51dc42]
    +             !     9125 mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8a51e686]
    +             4 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1529  [0x7fff83a67ad9]
    +             ! 3 __CFRunLoopDoTimer  (in CoreFoundation) + 557  [0x7fff83a8231d]
    +             ! : 3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__  (in CoreFoundation) + 20  [0x7fff83a82804]
    +             ! :   2 __NSFireTimer  (in Foundation) + 96  [0x7fff82073463]
    +             ! :   | 1 -[XRTrace _runTimerTickFireMethod:]  (in InstrumentsPlugIn) + 103  [0x10ab7829b]
    +             ! :   | + 1 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]  (in CoreFoundation) + 359  [0x7fff83b54697]
    +             ! :   | +   1 calloc  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 0  [0x7fff8c083bf4]
    +             ! :   | 1 -[XRTrace _runTimerTickFireMethod:]  (in InstrumentsPlugIn) + 172  [0x10ab782e0]
    +             ! :   |   1 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]  (in Foundation) + 64  [0x7fff820487b6]
    +             ! :   |     1 _CFXNotificationPost  (in CoreFoundation) + 2554  [0x7fff83a77eda]
    +             ! :   |       1 -[XRInstrument _tick:]  (in InstrumentsPlugIn) + 26  [0x10ab7831e]
    +             ! :   |         1 -[XRInstrument requiresTickNotification]  (in InstrumentsPlugIn) + 1  [0x10ab9c823]
    +             ! :   1 __NSFireTimer  (in Foundation) + 135  [0x7fff8207348a]
    +             ! :     1 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop  (in CoreFoundation) + 34  [0x7fff83a62d72]
    +             ! :       1 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 464  [0x7fff858b0230]
    +             ! :         1 -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc]  (in CoreFoundation) + 286  [0x7fff83b554ee]
    +             ! :           1 object_dispose  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 22  [0x7fff858affa0]
    +             ! :             1 objc_destructInstance  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 121  [0x7fff858af940]
    +             ! :               1 objc_clear_deallocating  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 151  [0x7fff858af9ee]
    +             ! :                 1 arr_clear_deallocating  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 31  [0x7fff858c60c4]
    +             ! :                   1 weak_entry_for_referent(weak_table_t*, objc_object*)  (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 235  [0x7fff858c5f98]
    +             ! 1 __CFRunLoopDoTimer  (in CoreFoundation) + 501  [0x7fff83a822e5]
    +             !   1 mk_timer_arm  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8a51e7b2]
    +             1 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 891  [0x7fff83a6785b]
    +             ! 1 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort  (in CoreFoundation) + 195  [0x7fff83a62233]
    +             !   1 mach_msg  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 70  [0x7fff8a51dc42]
    +             !     1 mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8a51e686]
    +             1 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1186  [0x7fff83a67982]
    +             ! 1 __CFRunLoopDoObservers  (in CoreFoundation) + 48  [0x7fff83a8c240]
    +             1 __CFRunLoopRun  (in CoreFoundation) + 1400  [0x7fff83a67a58]
    +               1 CFArrayAppendValue  (in CoreFoundation) + 91  [0x7fff83a40e6b]
    +                 1 -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]  (in CoreFoundation) + 728  [0x7fff83a76438]
    +                   1 __bzero  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 0  [0x7fff8c0571a3]
    9132 Thread_10178896   DispatchQueue_2: com.apple.libdispatch-manager  (serial)
    + 9132 _dispatch_mgr_thread  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 54  [0x7fff843019ee]
    +   9128 _dispatch_mgr_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 883  [0x7fff84301dea]
    +   ! 9128 kevent  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8a520d16]
    +   3 _dispatch_mgr_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 885  [0x7fff84301dec]
    +   1 _dispatch_mgr_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 144  [0x7fff84301b07]
    +     1 _dispatch_run_timers  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 306  [0x7fff84301f71]
    +       1 _dispatch_wakeup  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 106  [0x7fff842ffeb3]
    9132 Thread_10178898   DispatchQueue_184: parsing queue  (serial)
    + 9132 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff8c057191]
    +   9132 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 404  [0x7fff8c06ccdb]
    +     9132 _dispatch_worker_thread2  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 249  [0x7fff843001c3]
    +       9132 _dispatch_queue_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 52  [0x7fff843002f1]
    +         9132 _dispatch_queue_drain  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 235  [0x7fff8430047f]
    +           9132 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 8  [0x7fff842ff0b6]
    +             9132 _dispatch_call_block_and_release  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 15  [0x7fff84302f01]
    +               9132 __43-[DTXMessageParser initWithMessageHandler:]_block_invoke  (in DTXConnectionServices) + 35  [0x10b13fb36]
    +                 9132 -[DTXMessageParser parseMessage]  (in DTXConnectionServices) + 51  [0x10b13fd79]
    +                   9132 -[DTXMessageParser waitForMoreData:incrementalBuffer:]  (in DTXConnectionServices) + 87  [0x10b14012a]
    +                     9132 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 241  [0x7fff84302486]
    +                       9132 semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8a51e6c2]
    9132 Thread_10178984: com.apple.CFSocket.private
    + 9132 thread_start  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff8c0571a1]
    +   9132 _pthread_start  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 327  [0x7fff8c06a772]
    +     9132 __CFSocketManager  (in CoreFoundation) + 1302  [0x7fff83aa6f46]
    +       9132 __select  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8a520322]
    9132 Thread_10179054
    + 9132 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff8c057191]
    +   9132 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 412  [0x7fff8c06cce3]
    +     9132 _pthread_workq_return  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 25  [0x7fff8c06cf1c]
    +       9132 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8a5206d6]
    9131 Thread_10184560
    + 9131 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff8c057191]
    +   9131 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 412  [0x7fff8c06cce3]
    +     9131 _pthread_workq_return  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 25  [0x7fff8c06cf1c]
    +       9131 __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 10  [0x7fff8a5206d6]
    1 Thread_10184560   DispatchQueue_9: com.apple.root.high-overcommit-priority  (concurrent)
      1 start_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 13  [0x7fff8c057191]
        1 _pthread_wqthread  (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 404  [0x7fff8c06ccdb]
          1 _dispatch_worker_thread2  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 249  [0x7fff843001c3]
            1 _dispatch_queue_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 72  [0x7fff84300305]
              1 _dispatch_source_invoke  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 460  [0x7fff843011b4]
                1 _dispatch_client_callout  (in libdispatch.dylib) + 8  [0x7fff842ff0b6]
                  1 __CFRunLoopTimeoutCancel  (in CoreFoundation) + 18  [0x7fff83ab4cf2]
                    1 CFRelease  (in CoreFoundation) + 175  [0x7fff83a3b28f]

Total number in stack (recursive counted multiple, when >=5):

Sort by top of stack, same collapsed (when >= 5):
        __workq_kernreturn  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        18263
        __select  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        9132
        semaphore_wait_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        9132
        kevent  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        9128
        mach_msg_trap  (in libsystem_kernel.dylib)        9126
```

Comment: A sample of your integration test process when it's hung might help us diagnose the issue.  When the tests appear to have hung, in the terminal run `sample <your integration test process name>` and if the process name has spaces put it in quotation marks like `sample "My Cool App"`.

Comment: for clarity, when you say "your integration test process name", are you referring to the instruments process?  When I input - sample <test name>, I do not get a result however when I type - sample instruments, I get a huge output.

Comment: It should be the Product Name of the integration testing target you have set up in Xcode.

Comment: I tried searching for the process - ps aux | grep [I]ntegrationTestsUnity but only found the instruments process associated with my product name and the bash process associated with my product name.  Sorry for the noob comments but I have never used sample and it seems like the product name is not a process that is running at all, even when the test suite is running and not frozen.  Would you have any other suggestions?  BTW I posted the instruments stack in the question above.

Comment: In Xcode, if you select the project file at the very top of the file browser in the left toolbar, then select your integration test target in the "TARGETS" list for the project, then search for "Product Name" in Build Settings tab, you should see the name of the app that's built for your integration tests.  That product name is the argument you want to send to sample.

Comment: Hi Ray, is this you? https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/issues/104 If so I've responded there (and will post that issue's resolution back here once we've resolved it).

Answer (score 0):

An issue that could cause the tests to hang part-way through in certain environments was fixed by [inkling/Subliminal@ab22c43](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/commit/ab22c432b7745269ff76e04beb784be71b37d270), which went into [v1.1.0](https://github.com/inkling/Subliminal/releases/tag/v1.1.0).